# Creating pivot tables in a loop, each on their own new worksheet with a dynamic name VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, dynamic, pivot-table

Here is what I want the code to do

> for each row in column U create a new tab with a new pivot table based on a master worksheet's data

The issue is the dynamic table destination I believe. I am creating a variable, PayorName, which is based on a list in the "Master" worksheet. then I want the sheets the pivot tables are on to have the name "[company] Pivot"

am I trying to do too much at once?

Partial code:

```
Dim LastRowA As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
Dim LastRowU As Long
With ActiveSheet
    LastRowU = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
End With


ActiveSheet.Name = "Master"

'this loop is set to run the first 5 items temporarily
'later it will go to lastrowU
For i = 2 To 5

PayorName = Sheets("Master").Cells(i, "U").Value

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = PayorName & " Pivot"
With ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Master1!R1C1:R" & LastRowA)
        .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Sheets(PayorName & " Pivot").Range("A3"), TableName:="PivotTable"
End With
    Sheets(PayorName & " Pivot").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ' from here I set the pivot's fields
next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the pivot cache is too large to be done dynamically? I have tried this code and get an error when I try to set the pivot cache

```
Dim FinalRow            As Long
Dim DataSheet           As String
Dim PvtCache            As PivotCache
Dim PvtTbl              As PivotTable
Dim DataRng             As Range
Dim TableDest           As Range

Dim LastCol As Integer
    With ActiveSheet
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
DataSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

' set data range for Pivot Table
Set DataRng = Sheets(DataSheet).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(FinalRow, LastCol))
' set pivot cache
Set PvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, DataRng)
```

Then there is an error (Type Mismatch) on the last line (set pvtcache...), but the code continues as such

```
PayorName = Sheets("Master1").Cells(i, "U").Value

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = PayorName & " Pivot"

' set range for Pivot table placement
Set TableDest = Sheets(PayorName & " Pivot").Cells(3, 1)



' this line in case the Pivot table doesn't exit >> first time running this Macro
On Error Resume Next
Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables("PivotTable") ' check if "PivotTable4" Pivot Table already created (in past runs of this Macro)

On Error GoTo 0
If PvtTbl Is Nothing Then ' "PivotTable" doesn't exist >> create it

    ' create a new Pivot Table in "PivotTable" sheet
    Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(DataSheet).PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PvtCache, TableDestination:=TableDest, TableName:="PivotTable")

    ' setting fields
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "PivotTable1").PivotFields("Amount"), "Sum of Amount", xlSum
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Amount")
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);($#,##0.00)"
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("GL Debit Account")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Payment Payor")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        For x = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
            .PivotItems(.PivotItems(x).Name).Visible = False
        Next x
        .PivotItems(PayorName).Visible = True
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Post Date")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
        End With
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Batch #")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With
End If
```